# Pending sort hypotheses

Tags: isabelle

What could be the reason for the following error message:

```
Pending sort hypotheses: trelations
```

Here,

- trelations is a class type
- the error is generated when proving a collection of subgoals by contradiction. Subgoals are of the form: "premise1 ==> premise2 ==> False"
- the proof state says "No subgoals!", though.
- the assumptions of trelations are consistent to me (https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2012-July/msg00023.html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error arises because Isabelle can't know for sure that your assumptions are consistent. Here's a contrived example (from Brian Huffman):

```
class impossible =
  assumes impossible: "∃x. x ≠ x"

lemma False: "False"
proof -
  obtain x :: "'a::impossible" where "x ≠ x"
  using impossible ..
  then show "False" by simp
qed
```

Clearly, the system *must* reject this proof, because the `impossible` sort is empty. The technical reason why it is rejected is that the system doesn't know any instance of `impossible`.

There are two ways to prevent this from happening:

1. Before doing any proofs over classes, register an instance.
2. Add a "sort constraint" as an assumption for your lemma: `SORT_CONSTRAINT('a::trelations)`. It gets automatically discharged when you use the lemma (once you've registered an instance somewhere).